# What to use instead of 'GoTo'?

Tags: python, goto

The simplicity of this question is incredible and I must sound stupid, but how can I replace a GoTo in this piece of code?

```
Restart:
row1=random.randint(0,11)
If playerBoard[1,rowone] (is not empty):
GoTo Restart
```

I am trying to find out if the array with the key is empty. If it is, move on. If it is not, populate `row1` eith another random integer.

Comment: Python doesn't have a goto statement. Instead, you could use a while loop for the same checking.

Comment: is `playerBoard` a `np.array`? What is `empty`, `None`? `""`? You might want to run through the first few sections of [the tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/index.html), which cover control flow.

Comment: `GoTo` is so nineties

Answer (score 2):

You'd use a `while` loop:

```
while True:
    row1 = random.randint(0,11)
    if playerBoard[1][row1] is None:
        break
```

where I take empty cells to contain `None`.